# Chrome Extension: insert a user input string into multiple declarativeNetRequest regexSubstitution rules

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an extension that replaces the UTM parameter in URLs with the string `WTTDOTM`. It works by having a number of rulesets, each with an individual regexSubstitution rule. I did it this way because if I have multiple rules trying to do a regex substitution in the same ruleset, only one seems to execute (this will be relevant in a bit).

Here is one of the rules. **I am wondering if there is a way to collect a user input and have the json reference that input, so that instead of** `"regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2"` **the rule is changed to** `"regexSubstitution": "\\1[USER_INPUT]\\2"`.

utmsource.json

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_source=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

manifest.json (simplified w/o extra rules, they all follow the format of the above just with utm_medium/campaign/term/content substituted for utm_source:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "CustomUTM",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Custom UTM Extension",
    "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmsource.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"],
    "icons": {
          "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```

I know I can create dynamic rules with updateDynamicRules, but it seems as though all dynamic rules exist in the same ruleset which is where the multiple regexSubstitution conflict from earlier becomes relevant, because unless there is a way to make multiple different dynamic rulesets, only one substitution will actually execute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT ----

Below is an example of one json ruleset containing multiple regexSubstitution rules:

For the example input `https://about.fb.com/regulations/?utm_source=programmatic&utm_medium=paid-offplatform&utm_term=fillerterm&utm_content=fillercontent`

The actual output is `https://about.fb.com/regulations/?utm_source=programmatic&utm_medium=paid-offplatform&utm_term=fillerterm&utm_content=WTTDOTM`

While the desired output is `https://about.fb.com/regulations/?utm_source=WTTDOTM&utm_medium=paid-WTTDOTM&utm_term=WTTDOTM&utm_content=WTTDOTM`

It will always complete only the rule with the largest priority #. That is why I am concerned about updateDynamicRules, unless there is some weird regex formula I can use to condense these 4 rules into 1 for this substitution.

condensedruleset.json

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_source=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  },
{
    "id": 2,
    "priority": 2,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_medium=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "priority": 3,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_term=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "priority": 4,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_content=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

whereas if I do multiple rulesets like this, I get the desired output:

utmsource.json

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1Fuck%20Off%20My%20Data\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_source=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

utmmedium.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "\\1Fuck%20Off%20My%20Data\\2" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "(.*?utm_medium=).+?($|\\&.*)",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

and so on. The manifest for this looks like this:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "CustomUTM",
    "version": "1.3",
    "description": "Custom UTM Extension",
    "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmsource.json"
      },
      {
        "id": "ruleset_2",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmmedium.json"
      },
      {
        "id": "ruleset_3",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmcontent.json"
      },
      {
        "id": "ruleset_4",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmcampaign.json"
      },
      {
        "id": "ruleset_5",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "utmterm.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequest", "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"],
    "icons": {
          "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```

Comment: "in the same ruleset, only one seems to execute" - there should be no such limit technically so I guess it's because your regexFilter is matching the same URLs but I'd like to see at least two such rulesets to be sure. Anyway, the only solution is updateDynamicRules.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I added in an example of a condensed ruleset that doesn't work and the same rules broken out over multiple rulesets that do work. I think either I need to figure out how to make one regex rule that accomplishes all of those rulesets together or figure out how to make dynamic rules that don't conflict with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `transform` action for the query part, not `regexSubstitution`, and a condition that matches all the parameters.

```json
"condition": {
  "regexFilter": "[?&]utm_(source|medium|term|content)=[^&]+",
  "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
},
"action": {
  "type": "redirect",
  "redirect": {
    "transform": {
      "queryTransform": {
        "addOrReplaceParams": [
          {"key": "utm_source", "value": "foo"},
          {"key": "utm_medium", "value": "foo"},
          {"key": "utm_term", "value": "foo"},
          {"key": "utm_content", "value": "foo"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```